# How to make ajax get the data without refresh on jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, sharepoint

I want to be able to get the data using ajax without having to load the page to get the up to date data.

Here is the function I'm using to get the data from another page URL (I have to refresh to get the up to date data):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/data.aspx",
    success: function(myObj) {
        try {

            var d = new Date();
            var s = new String();
            var Day = d.getDate();
            var Month = d.getMonth() + 1;
            var Year = d.getFullYear();
            s = (Month + "/" + Day + "/" + Year).toString();
            var Start = myObj.indexOf("var WPQ1ListData = {");
            var End = myObj.indexOf("var WPQ1SchemaData");
            var Str = myObj.substring(Start + 19, End - 1);
            var Objects = Str.split(',');
            var count = 0;
            var AllEvents = "";
            $("#calendarItems").empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < Objects.length; i++) {
                if ((Objects[i].indexOf('Title') > -1) || (Objects[i].indexOf('"EventDate"') > -1)) {
                    count++;
                    TwoDimObjects = Objects[i].split(":");
                    AllEvents += TwoDimObjects[1];
                    if (count % 2 == 0) {
                        AllEvents += "_-_";
                    }
                }
            }
            var index1, index2, index3, Split, Decoded, FullDate, Month, YearwithTitle, Title, MonthNum, DayNum,
                YearNum, dateParts, months, selectedMonthName, CalendarItem, EventCounter;
            EventCounter = 0;
            CalendarItem = "";
            months = ["", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
            DiffDate = AllEvents.split('"').join(' ');
            DiffDate2 = DiffDate.split("_-_");
            for (var j = 0; j < DiffDate2.length - 1; j++) {
                Decoded = DiffDate2[j].split("\\u002f").join("\\");
                Split = Decoded.substring(2, Decoded.length);
                index1 = Split.indexOf(" ");
                index2 = Split.indexOf("  ");
                YearwithTitle = Split.substr(0, index1) + Split.substr(index2 + 1);
                index3 = YearwithTitle.indexOf(" ");
                FullDate = YearwithTitle.substring(0, index3);
                Title = YearwithTitle.substring(index3 + 1, YearwithTitle.length);

                FullDate, dateParts = FullDate.split(/\\|\//), MonthNum = dateParts[0], DayNum = dateParts[1], YearNum = dateParts[2];

                ConvertDate = FullDate.split("\\").join("/");
                var CurrentDate = new Date(s);
                var CalendarItemDate = new Date(ConvertDate);
                if (CurrentDate <= CalendarItemDate) {
                    EventCounter++;
                    if (EventCounter <= 4) {
                        selectedMonthName = months[MonthNum];
                        CalendarItem += '<li>' + selectedMonthName + " " + DayNum + " - " + Title + '</li>';


                    }
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("calendarItems").innerHTML += CalendarItem;

        } catch (err) {
            alert(err)
        }
    }
}
```

);

Comment: Why don't you just make it a function and use a timer/button to call the function which will get the information and then update?

Comment: I don't know why i didn't think of that! Thank you very much.